# Does the etherscan api work with bsc chain?

Tags: dapp-development, bsc, dapp-design, ethers.js

Does the [etherscan api](https://etherscan.io/apis) work with bsc chain?

I am trying the code below but it does not work. Yet it works on rinkeby network.

```
const etherscanProvider = new providers.EtherscanProvider(
    56,
    config.etherscanApiKey
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Etherscan API docs](https://docs.etherscan.io/support/faq#which-networks-are-api-pro-endpoints-applicable-to):

> Every block explorer built by Etherscan ( eg. BscScan, PolygonScan, HecoInfo ) requires a different account to be created and hence a different set of API keys

Apparently you'll need to create a new API key for BSC. A good tip to keep in mind would be to always leverage the search function in any docs website.

Update: The issue is not only relevant to Etherscan API, there's also EthersJS's network support. I looked up [EtherJS's EtherscanProvider](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/api-providers/#EtherscanProvider) in the docs, it states the following:

> Supported Networks
>
> - Homestead (Mainnet)
> - Ropsten (proof-of-work testnet)
> - Rinkeby (proof-of-authority testnet)
> - Görli (clique testnet)
> - Kovan (proof-of-authority testnet)

It doesn't list BSC as a supported network, and so I think you'll have to use another provider for now.

Comment: And how do I set up the BSC network. It is like the network id is not working...

Comment: Chain id of 56 should work, as long as you're using the bsc API key.

Comment: Use the bscscan docs https://bscscan.com/apis

Comment: There's also an EthersJS issue to note, and so I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Can I use the JSON rpc to query bsc chain?

Comment: You have many web3 provider options for querying bsc on-chain data, I would suggest you look up Alchemy API.

Comment: I have used the apis provided by binance. For now, that will serve my needs.